# How to normalize LSTM input data in Keras with BatchNormalization

Tags: python, keras

I have my neural network constructed like the following:

```
tempIn = Input(shape = (None, 4))
tempModel = LSTM(data.xRnnLosFeatures)(tempIn)
tempModel = BatchNormalization()(tempModel)
tempModel = Activation('tanh')(tempModel)
tempModel = Dropout(0.5)(tempModel)
tempModel = Dense(1)(tempModel)
model = Model(inputs=tempIn, outputs=tempModel)
```

However, I keep getting a very large error if I do not manually normalize my input data before I feed this network. What is a way to normalize my input data correctly. I tried to add another one before LSTM layer but that doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scalerx = MinMaxScaler( feature_range=(0, 1) )  # To normalize the inputs
scalery = MinMaxScaler( feature_range=(0, 1) )  # To normalize the outputs

datax = scalerx.fit_transform( data['inputs'] ) # Assuming a dictionary with inputs
datay = scalerx.fit_transform( data['outputs'] ) # and outputs

model.fit( datax, datay )
```

After you run the model, you will get values in the range [0,1], and you need to revert the normalization to make sense of them:

```
y_hat = model.predict( some_data_normalized_with_scalerx )

y_hat_denorm = scalery.inverse_transform( y_hat )
```

and `y_hat_denorm` will have the same units from the beginning, i.e. those from `data['outputs']`, used to create `scalery`.

Comment: dude... it's an LSTM, you can't normalize the 3D input with a MinMaxScaler.

Comment: @KrustytheClown Could you please elaborate a little? I do not understand what you want to say.

Comment: MinMaxScaler will normalize a set of vectors, NOT a set of matrices. you can’t just toss sequences of data into it like that, a single MinMaxScaler doesn’t handle that many dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **keras** `normalise` function or alternatively you could use **scikit-learn** `preprocessing` function.

Comment: You should explain in detail how to use the functions that you've mentioned in the context of the question being asked, rather than simply saying those functions exist and can be used.